# Why is there a need for a Top Altitude in FAA's SIDs?

Tags: faa-regulations, instrument-procedures, departure-sid

I am examining some of the FAA's SID charts and, as far as I can deduce, each SID provides information concerning the altitude when it is necessary and, if not changed by the controller, each transition/route description will end with something such as "Maintain X altitude etc." which seems that it is the same as the Top Altitude.

Since this information is written in SID's textual description as "Maintain X altitude", why is there a need to exist also separately as Top Altitude?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking? The description page is just clarifying and reiterating the info on the graphic depiction. Are you just asking why they put it on there twice?

Comment: Yes, but I guess what you said ("The description page is just clarifying and reiterating the info on the graphic depiction") answers that. So both the Top Altitude and the "Maintain X attitude" textual description refer to the same thing?

Comment: That's what I believe.

Comment: @TomMcW thank you for your clarification, please feel free to post your comments as an answer, so I can mark it as the accepted one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is needed for the new *[climb-via](https://nbaa.org/aircraft-operations/communications-navigation-surveillance-cns/performance-based-navigation-pbn/climb-descend-via/)* instruction (c. 2014).

Instead of issuing different maintain altitudes to the aircraft based on the SID, direction, etc., a top altitude is charted. From the FAA AIM:

> SIDs will have a "top altitude;" the "top altitude" is the charted "maintain" altitude contained in the procedure description or assigned by ATC.

Related:

- [Do Jeppesen SIDs have top altitude?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/44678/14897)
- [What altitude should you cross DBIGE at on the PALLEY FIVE Departure (SID)?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/48915/14897)
- [Are 'climb via a SID' instructions actually used in the US?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/44811/14897)